# How can you use a function pointer with argument in c?

Tags: c, syntax, function-pointers

How can you use this function pointer declaration?

```
int (* get_function(char c)) (int, int);
```

I have three functions `int function_a(int a, int b)`, `int function_b(int a, int b)` and `int function_c(int a, int b)`. I want to use the above function pointer to call one of my functions conditionally based on `c`.

Comment: `int (* get_function(char c)) (int, int);` is not a function pointer, it is a function, getting a `char c` and returning a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function_a(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Inside function_a: %d %d\n", a, b);
    return a+b;
}

int function_b(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Inside function_b: %d %d\n", a, b);
    return a+b;
}

int function_c(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Inside function_c: %d %d\n", a, b);
    return a+b;
}

int function_whatever(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Inside function_whatever: %d %d\n", a, b);
    return a+b;
}


int (* get_function(char c)) (int, int)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'A':
            return function_a;
        case 'B':
            return function_b;
        case 'C':
            return function_c;
    }
    return function_whatever;
}

int main(void) {
    get_function('B')(3, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

`get_function('B')` returns a function pointer to `function_b` and `get_function('B')(3, 5);` also calls that function.

https://ideone.com/0kUp47